# Не сохраняется куки в мобилке (браузер Chrome) - PHP

Tags: php, cookie

Не понимаю почему каждый раз не сохраняются куки, когда открываю сайт и авторизуюсь у меня отркывается профиль, после того что я закрываю браузер Хром на мобильном и последующее отркываю сайт снова то у меня заново просит логин и пароль

на PHP сделал таким образом:

```
setcookie("userid", $s_id, time()+7776000, '/', 'domain.com');
```

Также сделал:

```
setcookie("userid", $s_id, time() + (86400 * 365));
```

всё равно после закрытия браузера приходится заново авторизоваться

Comment: Какая логика у вас в авторизации? что в переменной $s_id?

Comment: Обычно, если не устанавливать правила куков, все неопределённый параметры работают до его закрытия. Установите сохранения куков до одной недели и будет счастье

Comment: @Николай сможете пример показать ?

Comment: time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 7